# What would happen if one drank only D2O for a long time?

Tags: water

Would it be lethal ? Would you gain 10% of your body weigth ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the physiological response to drinking [heavy water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water) and not physics.

Comment: Asking what will happen to your body if you ingest something is probably better suited for biology.SE; we could probably tell you whether D2O is lethal immediately, but a biologist is better suited for telling you about weight gain or what would happen if the overall density of your body increased, etc.

Comment: And you'd sink well when swimming

Comment: Insufficient effort? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water#Toxicity_in_humans

Comment: You'd go broke?

Comment: @dmckee: You should add that to the wikipedia page on heavy water. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Heavy Water is toxic to most organisms. Usually, an organism will die before half of their body's water has been replaced by heavy water (which would require ingestion of very large amounts of heavy water and limited ingestion of regular water). It's toxic because it inhibits cell division and slows down the rate of life processes. It would slow your metabolism and will cause cell putrefaction. Consumption in small amounts wouldn't be too harmful but chronic exposure, like you mentioned, will cause lot of complications.